# Maven does not find locally installed package

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to use a third party jar in my project (Z3 specifically).
The third part jar is not built with `mvn`, so I add it using this command:

```
mvn install:install-file                        \                                                   
    -Dfile="$z3_build_dir"/com.microsoft.z3.jar \                                                   
    -DgroupId=com.microsoft                     \                                                   
    -DartifactId=z3                             \                                                   
    -Dversion=1.0.0                             \                                                   
    -Dpackaging=jar                             \                                                   
    -DgeneratePom=true
```

I've added a dependency to my project's pom file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.microsoft</groupId>
  <artifactId>z3</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I can see the installed file here `~/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/z3/1.0.0/z3-1.0.0.pom`.

However, I'm seeing this warnings and error:

```
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/microsoft/z3/1.0.0/z3-1.0.0.pom
Downloading from other-repo: https://other-repo/repository/internal/org/microsoft/z3/1.0.0/z3-1.0.0.pom
[WARNING] The POM for org.microsoft:z3:jar:1.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/microsoft/z3/1.0.0/z3-1.0.0.jar
Downloading from other-repo: https://other-repo/repository/internal/org/microsoft/z3/1.0.0/z3-1.0.0.jar
...
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project java-backend: Could not resolve [redacted] Could not find artifact org.microsoft:z3:jar:1.0.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

The Maven documentation says I need to do nothing extra to find locally installed packages, so I don't understand why it's searching Central.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pom entry is wrong. It should be (based on your install command)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft</groupId>
  <artifactId>z3</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

The groupId has to match. Change

```
<groupId>org.microsoft</groupId>
```

to

```
<groupId>com.microsoft</groupId>
```

like you specified here:

```
mvn install:install-file                        \                                                   
    -Dfile="$z3_build_dir"/com.microsoft.z3.jar \                                                   
    -DgroupId=com.microsoft                     \                                                   
    -DartifactId=z3                             \                                                   
    -Dversion=1.0.0                             \                                                   
    -Dpackaging=jar                             \                                                   
    -DgeneratePom=true*
```

Comment: Ow. Thanks. That typo just cost me 3 hours